# How to restore default cmd behaviour in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

In Windows 10, when I used to type `cmd` in Run. The PowerShell was used to open inside black cmd like window.

My friend has somehow made cmd open cmd.exe, which was default in the previous version of Windows, but not Windows 10. Now he doesn't remember how he did.

How do I reset to open PowerShell inside cmd?

Comment: Are you talking about Win+X key combo menu?

Comment: I changed that in Taskbar personalization menu.

Comment: Typing CMD in Run doesn't open Powershell naturally. Did you configure it manually? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I assume you want the command prompt instead of a PowerShell prompt.  If that isn't the case, then you should edit your question, so it isn't unclear.  PowerShell has only been the default behavior since I believe 1703, before that, it was 1709.  The steps to revert the changes your friend likely made, are in an answer to the duplicate question, which I am treating as a duplicate unless you provide details on what your friend did (which will be difficult given the description).